# Fetching all the repositories of a Project in git

Tags: bash, git, shell, bitbucket

I have url like this https://git.company.com/project. I am trying to write a shell script which tries to fetch all the repositories of a given Project. Additionally, I want to find the commit history of all those repositories under that project. what is the way to write a shell script for the same?

```
previous_branch=remotes/origin/release/${Previous_Release_Number}
current_branch=remotes/origin/release/${Present_Release_Number}
git log --pretty=format:"%ae, %s, %cd"  ${previous_branch}..${current_branch} |sort> output.csv
```

This I have written for single repository.

Comment: How are the projects listed? Is there an API you can use? What software is used to host the remote repositories?

Comment: All the repositories are hosted in Bitbucket under one project. I want to fetch the commit history of all the repositoris under that project. is it possible through git command?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by `repositories` you are talking about [remotes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) of that repository.

[Git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) has several options you can use, one of them being `--all` which would then fetch updates from all `remotes`:

```
git fetch --all
```

Happy to extend my answer if you provide more information about what you want to do exactly.

Cheers,
Dominic

Comment: hey @Dominic its the remotes. What i am trying here is that i have url to Bitbucket where there are several remote repositories. Now my problem is to fetch all those remotes using the given URL.

Comment: @KoushikJ Alright. Just to clarify: Are we talking about different remotes for the same repository or multiple, different repositories? I suspect the latter but just to make sure ..

Comment: Ok, so you got multiple URL you want to pull from. And also multiple folders they go in to? So no connection at all? Or all into one folder (which I can't see any use for yet)?

Comment: There is no connection between invidual Remore repositories...they are all under one Base URL..that is the main project thats it..